# Confused on Ionic update

Tags: angularjs, reactjs, react-native, cordova, ionic3

I am currently working on Ionic 3 on several projects.
To keep up with the latest updates I need to upgrade to Ionic 5.

Now, the ionic 5 upgrade seems to re-work almost on all of my code. So I am confused about whether I should upgrade to Ionic 5 or should change the framework to React or Vue?

Another issue is most of the Cordova plugins I use are not currently supported(in other words, are not maintained anymore.)

Please share your thoughts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're mixing multiple questions here.

**How do I migrate from v3 to v5?**

The Ionic-Team made a lot of API-Changes from v3 to v4. They moved their components from angular to web-components and now support bindings to multiple frameworks. There is no automated migration from v3 to v4, so the easiest way might be to create a new ionic project and transfer and refactor your code manually.

**Should I use angular, react, vue or vanillajs?**

There is no automated migration, so the only benefit of this is, that you can now think about changing the framework. If you continue using angular, it might be the fastest way, as you only have to refactor according to API changes.

Also in the tags you wrote angularjs (angular v1), but ionic3 is using (angular v2), so I assume your code is written with angular.

**What should I do with unmaintained cordova plugins?**

I don't think you have many options here. You can switch to capacitor if you prefer the development process and use cordova plugins for functionality that capacitor has no plugin yet. There are many cordova plugins that work and are not well maintained. But if something is not working, you have to contribute to the plugin, remove the functionality from your app or write the native code yourself (e.g. with capacitor).

Answer (score 1):

I would go with Ionic 5 together with capacitor which I think is a much better experience to work with than ionic 3 and Cordova.

Comment: Yes right! it's better than ionic3-cordova but I have noticed that the capacitor doesn't support many plugins like screen-orientation, code push, flurry analytics, deep links etc...

https://capacitorjs.com/docs/apis

after update ionic 5 with the capacitor still we have to depend on Cordova plugins.